# How to add keyListner to a JOptionPane.showInputDialog()?

Tags: java, keylistener

I want to add keyListner on Input Dialog. When i press a key it will gives key code of pressed key. Below is complete code for JTextField its working for JTextField. I tried it on Input Dialog via `String n = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter a key")` but it says that keyListner unidentified for String operation.

*please edit my code for Input dialog

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class KeyListnerExample extends JFrame implements KeyListener{

    String KeyCodeT = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter a key");//A Text Field that will display the key code.

    public KeyListnerExample(){
      KeyCodeT.addKeyListener(this);//Listens for key inputs in the text field
      KeyCodeT.setEditable(false);//disallow user input into the Text field.
      add(KeyCodeT);//add the text field to the screen
      setSize(300,300);//set the screen size
      setVisible(true);//show the window on screen.     
    }
        //Called when the key is pressed down.
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        System.out.println("Key Pressed!!!");

        e.getKeyCode();
        System.out.println("key code is: " +e.getKeyCode());

    }

    //Called when the key is released   
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
        System.out.println("Key Released!!!");
        KeyCodeT.setText("Key Code:" + e.getKeyCode());//displays the key code in the text box

    }
    //Called when a key is typed
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){


    }

     public static void main(String[] args){
      KeyListnerExample key = new KeyListnerExample();
     }

}
```

Comment: Where did you try the JOptionPane in your code? I see no sign of it? Show the code that is giving the error.

Comment: ok i send in shortly

Comment: KeyCodeT is a string and you cannot attach a KeyListener to a String.

Comment: edited my code. please see 4th line of code.

Comment: how can i do it for input dialog? @Raf

Comment: There is two thing we need to understand? First, I don't know why you want to have a JOptionPane.showInputDialog? Are you taking input from user? Second, do you mean JOptionPane.showMessageDilaog() to display the code of key pressed on it?

Comment: firstly: yes, i need to take input from user.

Comment: secondly: no, i need show key code on console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95601/discussion-between-raf-and-zohaib-siddique).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a hint for what you can do:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class KeyListnerExample extends JFrame implements KeyListener{
    JTextField KeyCodeT;

    public KeyListnerExample(){
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        KeyCodeT = new JTextField();
        KeyCodeT.setOpaque(false);
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
        panel.add(KeyCodeT);
        JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, panel, "Enter Key Code", JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, null, null);
      KeyCodeT.addKeyListener(this);//Listens for key inputs in the text field
      KeyCodeT.setEditable(false);//disallow user input into the Text field.
      add(KeyCodeT);//add the text field to the screen
      setSize(300,300);//set the screen size
      setVisible(true);//show the window on screen.     
    }
        //Called when the key is pressed down.
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        System.out.println("Key Pressed!!!");

        e.getKeyCode();
        System.out.println("key code is: " +e.getKeyCode());

    }

    //Called when the key is released   
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
        System.out.println("Key Released!!!");
        KeyCodeT.setText("Key Code:" + e.getKeyCode());//displays the key code in the text box

    }
    //Called when a key is typed
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){


    }

     public static void main(String[] args){
      KeyListnerExample key = new KeyListnerExample();
     }

}
```

As you can see, I created a JPanel and added text field to it instead. Its easier to manage that way. Then finally used JOptionPane's [OptionDialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#create) to display stuff.

You can also use `KeyCodeT.setBorder(null);` if you dont want that black border. But that will give you an absurd dialog where you will have to make a guess-click in the middle.

EDIT: (Practically what @kamel2005 said in his answer).

Comment: correct answer but your code display also text field. Kindly tell me how to hide it. I don't want to display this text field

Comment: you can set use `KeyCodeT.setOpaque(false)` and you wont see text field. EDIT: Check my edited code.

Answer (score 1):

**You can try something like below :**

Here you can create a text field by adding keyListener and that text field can be passed to the JoptionPane .

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame parent = new JFrame();
    JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane();
    JTextField field = getField();
    optionPane.setMessage(new Object[]{"Type something: ", field});
    optionPane.setMessageType(JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    optionPane.setOptionType(JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
    JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog(parent, "My Customized OptionPane");
    dialog.setVisible(true);

}

private static JTextField getField() {
    JTextField field = new JTextField();
    field.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Input: " + e.getKeyChar());
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        }
    });
    return field;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a JPane Control that contains the control that will broadcast the key event  to your key Listener.
for example JTextField and then add your key listener to text field.
the Pane can be passed as a parameter to "JOptionPane"

Comment: i don't understand please edit my code to clear your answer.

Comment: I will put a code snippet giving you example how to implement this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
 JPanel jPane = new JPanel();
    TextField field = new TextField();
    jPane.add(field);
    field.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

        }
    });
    if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,jPane,"Panel Title", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION)== JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
        System.out.println(field.getText());
    }
```

Comment: correct answer but your code display also text field. Kindly tell me how to hide it. I don't want to display this text field

Comment: if you hide the TextField, there will be no control  that receive key input, thus there will be no key event to listen to.

Comment: I wanna just advice you, do not complicate things, make life easy for you. More complicated code more contains bugs and more difficult to maintain.

Comment: right saying but what will be the correct solution?

Comment: choose that works fine for you. I used example I given you in many cases. you can also add other controls to that JOptionPane if you want. For example JLabel to explain some thing to the end-user. And This example use static method of JOptionPane with less footprint.

Comment: bro. i can't find solution.

Comment: my be this one helps you.